# How do I get the sum and carry expression for ripple carry adder?

Tags: digital-logic, integrated-circuit, digital-communications

[image]please check the photo and kindly let me know how to find the expression.
I know sum expression only with xor gate. Cannot come to this conclusion.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

If you want the formula: it is right there on your picture.

If you want to know how to derive those formula from the logic diagram: simply take the expresseions for each gate and combine them.